# design pattern with jquery in tel and celphone form saving in mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, html, servlets

Hi I  have a webform cadastra.jsp that contains a field for telephone and celphone. My Mysql Db has a colunm for pf_telefone and pf_celular int(10) not null respectively. And i have a jquery function to design inputs for these fields. Look:

```
<script>
                    jQuery(function($){
                        $("#tel").mask("(99) 9999-9999");

                    });
                </script>
<script>
                    jQuery(function($){
                        $("#cel").mask("(99) 9999-9999");

                    });
                </script>
```

My servlet:

```
    public class AddDados extends HttpServlet{
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   
            throws IOException, ServletException { 


 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 String telefone = request.getParameter("tel");
 String celular = request.getParameter("cel");
```

But i got  a error HTTP Status 500 - com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect integer value: '(98) 8714-3765' for column 'pf_telefone' at row 1
how may i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, (98) 8714-3765 is not an integer. If that is the format you need to store phone number sin then you will need to convert your database fields to be chars. I think char(14) will work for you based on the masks you are using.

Alternatively, if you really do want to store them as Integers, you should change your input mask accordingly.

Comment: In your opinion what the best design pattern for this field type integer or char(varchar)?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data you are storing? That should inform your choice of storage. If you just want to display it back to a user I suggest you keep it in the same format they entered it.

Answer (score 0):

Either don't use an INT field type (rather use a textual type), or remove the and non-numeric characters from the data you are inserting.